# Evaluation of notebook from chosen cell to end

Tags: notebooks, cells

There is option to evaluate the complete notebook but I wanted to know if its possible to evaluate notebook from some desired cell to end or some other desired cell following?

Comment: You could always left click the cell where you want to start, scroll down to the bottom and press shift while left clicking the last cell and then right click on any of the selected cells and choose "evaluate cells"

Comment: Set the cells initialization or cell tags.

Comment: I regularly do `Ctrl+A` and then `Ctrl+click` to deselect different cells.

Comment: I have a feeling there is a similar question on this site long time ago, but I can't find it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work as you wish?

```
CreatePalette@Button["Evaluate down", 
  With[{nb = InputNotebook[]},
   SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell];
   With[{prevCell = SelectedCells[nb] /. {c_} :> c},
    Function[cell,
      SelectionMove[cell, All, Cell];
      SelectionEvaluateCreateCell@nb
      ]~Scan~
     Intersection[
      Reverse@TakeWhile[Reverse@Cells[nb], # =!= prevCell &], 
      Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Input"]]]
   ]
  ]
```