# Evaluation of notebook from a cell to another

Tags: evaluation, notebooks

I have a very simple notebook like this:

```
Quit[]
a = 10;
Sin[a]
k = 10;
Plot[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}]
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]
k = 0.8;
Sin[k]
A = {1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 4};
ListPlot[A]
```

I want evaluate with "one click" the code from `k = 10;` to `A = {1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 4};`, ignoring the rest;

I try with `Ctrl+A`, then `Ctrl+click` to deselect unnecessary cells and then `Enter` but mathematica evaluate only one cell.

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26209/evaluation-of-notebook-from-chosen-cell-to-end) is a very similar question, but
it looks like it does not work for me.

Comment: How is your notebook structured? Is this all in one cell? Are these in separate cells?

Comment: Yes, are separate cells

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: And what is the decision procedure for when you've hit the end cell? I think the easiest thing to do here is to just wrap things in a cell group, because then you can click on the group bracket and evaluate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I try with Ctrl+A, then Ctrl+click to deselect unnecessary cells and then Enter but mathematica evaluate only one cell.

You should use the `Evaluation ▶ Evaluate Cells` menu item:

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/EvaluateCells.html

Note that this can be easily found in the Docs:

http://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=Evaluate+selected+Cells

Comment: I am having trouble with running a tagged cell in `nb1` from `nb2`. I created various cells initialized and tagged in `nb1`, and I like to retrieve and run those tagged cells into `nb2`. Can you help me in doing this?

Comment: @TugrulTemel [Answered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/210872/280).