# Retrieving the evaluation result of an Initialization Cell in a notebook `nb1` from another notebook `nb2`

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, code-request

I have a very long code in a notebook `nb1` in which all the initialization cells are tagged. I have another notebook `nb2` where I want to evaluate the initialization cells in `nb1` and get the results in `nb2` by using `CellTags`.

I tried the following code, which does something but I cannot see the results in `nb2`.

```
myButton[tag_] := 
Button["Evaluate " <> tag, 
NotebookEvaluate[
"C:\\Users\\ttemel\\Desktop\\World_Bank_projects\\WB_Contract_2\\\
Extension_to_1st_contract_27oct19\\IOdatabase_oecd\\database_IOtables_\
SA_NO_UK_2000_2015_run_1.m", EvaluationElements -> {"Tags" -> {tag}}],
Method -> "Queued"];
Grid[{Map[myButton, {"SectorIOMarketChains", "DensityPlot"}]}]
CellPrint[
ExpressionCell[Defer[Print["SectorIOMarketChains"]], "Input", 
CellTags -> {"SectorIOMarketChains"}, ShowCellTags -> True]]
CellPrint[
ExpressionCell[Defer[Print["DensityPlot"]], "Input", 
CellTags -> {"DensityPlot"}, ShowCellTags -> True]]
```

Why does not this code give me the results in `nb2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file `"database_IOtables _SA _NO _UK _ 2000_ 2015_run _ 1.m"` isn't a Notebook, but a Package - right? Hence the `EvaluationElements` option is simply ignored, because Packages has no `Cell`s and associated `CellTag`s.

Obviously, you are trying to adapt the code from the section `Examples ► Applications` on the Documentation page for [`NotebookEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookEvaluate.html).

Here is how it is supposed to work:

1. Create a Notebook with your cells:

   ```
   nb = CreateDocument[{
          ExpressionCell[Defer[Print["SectorIOMarketChains"]], "Input", 
           CellTags -> {"SectorIOMarketChains"}, ShowCellTags -> True],
          ExpressionCell[Defer[Print["DensityPlot"]], "Input", CellTags -> {"DensityPlot"}, 
           ShowCellTags -> True]
          }];
   ```
2. In current Notebook create `Button`s for evaluating tagged cells from that Notebook:

   ```
   myButton[nb_, tag_] := 
     Button["Evaluate " <> tag, 
      NotebookEvaluate[nb, EvaluationElements -> {"Tags" -> {tag}}], Method -> "Queued"];
   Grid[{Map[myButton[nb, #] &, {"SectorIOMarketChains", "DensityPlot"}]}]
   ```

   > [image: screenshot]
3. Sequentially press the buttons, the results will appear in current Notebook:

   > [image: screenshot]

When working with an existing Notebook, on the first step you should use `NotebookOpen` (possibly with the option `Visible -> False` if you don't want it to be displayed):

```
nb = NotebookOpen[filePath, Visible -> False];
```

Do not forget to close the invisible Notebook when it is no longer needed:

```
NotebookClose[nb]
```

You can get the list of currently opened Notebooks (including invisible) via `Notebooks`:

```
Notebooks[]
```

---

Note that `NotebookEvaluate` is a relatively old function, introduced when `CellObject` wasn't available. Similar (but not exactly the same) effect can be achieved with `Cells` and `ToExpression`:

```
ToExpression[NotebookRead[Cells[nb, CellTags -> {"SectorIOMarketChains"}]][[1, 1]]]
```

> SectorIOMarketChains

You can see what `ToExpression` returns using its three-argument form:

```
ToExpression[
 NotebookRead[Cells[nb, CellTags -> {"SectorIOMarketChains"}]][[1, 1]], StandardForm, Hold]
```

> ```
> Hold[Print["SectorIOMarketChains"]]
> ```

Comment: @TugrulTemel In my explanation "current Notebook" means a new Notebook (`nb2`). The existing Notebook I call simply `nb` (it should be a `NotebookObject`), you don't need to modify it in any way. If the *existing Notebook* is already open, you shouldn't use its name at all, - but you should use its `NotebookObject`  which you can get from `Notebooks[]` (it returns the complete list of `NotebookObject`s for all opened Notebooks, including invisible Notebooks).

Comment: @TugrulTemel You can have a trouble with selecting the *existing Notebook* from the list returned by `Notebooks[]`. This is why I recommend to save your *existing Notebook* and use `nb = NotebookOpen[filePath];` for opening it and getting the `NotebookObject` (for the start). It isn't nesessary, but it will simplify your start.

Comment: @TugrulTemel When you receive the `NotebookEvaluate::nbnfnd` message, is your Notebook opened (really)? Please check, whether the Notebook opened with `NotebookOpen` is really opened.

Comment: @TugrulTemel I observed similar behavior initially, but later the `nb` wasn't closed after pressing the button. I think that it is a bug. If you stably reproduce it, please report it to the tech support: `NotebookEvaluate` shouldn't close an already opened Notebook which is supplied as the first argument.

Comment: @TugrulTemel As a workaround you could try the method described at the bottom of my answer: via `Cells` and `ToExpression`.

Comment: @TugrulTemel No, it isn't a good practice. With default settings all opened Notebooks have ``"Global`"`` context (you can check it by evaluating `Context[]`) and use the same WolframKernel process. Hence all variables are shared between all opened Notebooks, and `nb` will be available in `nb2` after evaluating `nb=NotebookOpen[filePath]` in `nb1`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion by replacing `NotebookEvaluate[nb, EvaluationElements -> {"Tags" -> {tag}}]` with  `ToExpression[NotebookRead[Cells[nb, CellTags -> {"SectorIOMarketChains"}]][[1, 1]]]`, but then I received the message: `ToExpression::notstrbox: NotebookRead[$Failed] is not a string or a box. ToExpression can only interpret strings or boxes as Wolfram Language input`. good news is that the required notebook `nb` is not closed this time.

Comment: @TugrulTemel `$Failed` output of `Cells` indicates that `nb` doesn't refer to an opened Notebook. Please repeat the steps: 1) `nb=NotebookOpen[filePath]`; 2)  `ToExpression[NotebookRead[Cells[nb, CellTags -> {"SectorIOMarketChains"}]][[1, 1]]]`.

Comment: This time it looks like `nb2` is doiung something, but no output is shown in `nb2`. All the required notebooks are shown as open. This is what I run in `nb2`:  `myButton[nb_, tag_] := 
  Button["Evaluate: " <> tag, 
   ToExpression[
    NotebookRead[Cells[nb, CellTags -> {"SectorIOMarketChains"}]][[1, 
      1]]], Method -> "Queued"];
Grid[{Map[myButton[nb, #] &, {"SectorIOMarketChains"}]}]`

Comment: @TugrulTemel What `Cells[nb, CellTags -> {"SectorIOMarketChains"}]]` returns?

Comment: I get `ToExpression::notstrbox: Cell[BoxData[{RowBox[{RowBox[{RowBox[<<1>>],;}],
}],
,RowBox[{RowBox[{RowBox[<<1>>],:=,RowBox[<<1>>]}],;}],
,RowBox[{RowBox[{RowBox[<<1>>],;},
:=] is not a string or a box. ToExpression can only interpret strings or boxes as Wolfram Language input` when I use `Cells[]`.

Comment: I got it!!!! I use `NotebookEvaluate[nb, 
 EvaluationElements -> {"Tags" -> {"SectorIOMarketChains"}}]` in `nb2`. I will now write what I did to achive my objective. Thank you very much for your extensive help.